# I want to add a group and give it the permission to edit the salary, how to do that in django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Where can I add group and permissions (i.e Models or views or admin) and where can I change the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally after your your database schema is being created you would like to create this permissions. In that case you can use `signals.post_syncdb.connect(...)` that runs every time you run syncdb command. Since permission is administrative task I personally think it is more relevant to add it at your `admin.py` but you can put it anywhere.

```
def editor_group_permissions(sender, **kwargs):
    editor=Group.objects.get_or_create(name='editor')[0]


    for m in ["Article", "popular Article", "slider Article"]:
        for p in ["add","change","delete"]:
            perm=Permission.objects.get(name="Can "+p+" "+m)
            editor.permissions.add(perm)
            print perm," on ",m, "granted for editor"


    ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', model='user')
    staff_approve_perm=Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_approve_staff',
                                                        name="Can approve staff",
                                                        content_type=ct)[0]
    print staff_approve_perm," on ","staff", "granted for editor"
    editor.permissions.add(staff_approve_perm)

from django.db.models import signals
signals.post_syncdb.connect(editor_group_permissions)
signals.post_syncdb.connect(author_group_permissions)
```

Comment: okay this might help, let me edit it to my requirements. But do i need to run syncdb everytime i need to add permissions??

Comment: end of running syncdb you have your desired permission and you a group that has a permission. Now if you do `user.group.append(group)` the user will be have that permission.

Comment: Just one more question, i have to define the permission under the model which i want to have permissions? right ?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following code for each new model you created.

```
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission , Group

    def add_permission(model_class_name, app, readble_class_name):


        ctype = ContentType(name = readble_class_name, app_label=app, model=model_class_name)
        try:
            ctype.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            ctype = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app, model=model_class_name)

        viewers = Group.objects.get(name='viewer')
        editors = Group.objects.get(name='editor')

        options = [('view', [viewers, editors]) ,('add',[editors]), ('change',[editors]), ('delete',[])]

        for opt in options: 
            perm = Permission(name = 'can %s %s' % (opt[0], readble_class_name) , content_type=ctype, codename = '%s_%s' % (opt[0], model_class_name))
            perm.save()

            for g in opt[1]: 
                g.permissions.add(perm)
```

then on User Admin, you have 'Groups' under the account tab.
create a new group, drag the permissions you like to have to that group.

then you can go to requested user via admin, and give him to be under the requested group.